# Python script to convert adblock list in a forbidden file for Polipo proxy (regex)

Tags: regex, python

On my system I currently running Polipo proxy, mainly for adblock purposes.
By a search on internet I've found many shell scripts to convert adblock plus lists in [Polipo forbidden file format](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/manual/Internal-forbidden-list.html); most of these scripts rely on sed, ruby or python.
However none of them is able to generate a valid forbidden file: when I restart Polipo with the new generated forbidden file, in the Polipo's log file I see the message: "`Couldn't compile regex: Unmatched ( or \(`"

The following python script which I attempt to use, is intended to convert an easylist file in a Polipo's forbidden file format:

```
#!/bin/python

# convert adblock ruleset into polipo-forbidden format

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import os
    import sys
    import re

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        sys.exit("Usage: %s <adblockrules>" % os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))

    if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
        sys.exit("The rules file (%s) doesn't exist" % sys.argv[1])

    fhandle = file(sys.argv[1])
    lines = fhandle.readlines()
    fhandle.close()

    dollar_re = re.compile("(.*?)\$.*")

    for line in lines:
        if line:
            if (line[0] in ("[", "!", "~", "#", "@") or
                line.startswith("/adverti") or
                "##" in line):
                continue
            line = dollar_re.sub(r"\1", line)
#           line = line.replace("|http://", "")
            line = line.replace("|", "")
            line = line.replace("||", "")
            line = line.replace(".", r"\.")
            line = line.replace("*", ".*")
            line = line.replace("?", r"\?")
            line = line.replace("^", r"[\/:\.=&\?\+\-\ ]+")
#           line = line.replace("&", r"\&")
#           line = line.replace("+", r"\+")
#           line = line.replace("-", r"\-")
#           line = line.replace(";", r"\;")
#           line = line.replace("=", r"\=")
#           line = line.replace("/", r"\/")
            print(line.strip())
    print("")
```

But as I've said, when I actualize this forbidden file, Polipo will claim "`Couldn't compile regex: Unmatched ( or \(`"

This one  is the forbidden file generated by the script
http://wikisend.com/download/494664/forbidden.conf

As I've said, online, there are many scripts like the one which I use, some of them also relies on sed, but no one seems able to generate a valid forbidden file (Polipo will always claims "Couldn't compile regex").
This is not a Polipo's fault, because if I made a clean forbidden file with some web url inside, Polipo will properly block these connections.

Can someone help me and explain how to modify/make a proper script to convert adblock lists in a valid regex forbidden file for Polipo?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an Adblock rule to a Python regex using https://github.com/scrapinghub/adblockparser library:

```
>>> from adblockparser import AdblockRule
>>> rule = AdblockRule("/ad/loaders/*")
>>> print(rule.regex)
/ad/loaders/.*
```

I'm not sure Polipo suports the same regex format though; regexes can get pretty hairy:

```
>>> print(AdblockRule("||example.com$").regex)
^(?:[^:/?#]+:)?(?://(?:[^/?#]*\.)?)?example\.com
```

Also take care of rules with options; it may be better to remove them because semantics is different.

Hope this helps.